# How can I count the number of posts that have either zero or positive vote score?

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have this table:

```
// qanda
+----+----------------------------------------+---------+-----------+------+
| Id |                   body                 | related |  user_id  | free |
+----+----------------------------------------+---------+-----------+------+
| 1  | content of question1                   | null    | 2         | null |
| 2  | content of first answer for question1  | 1       | 2         | null |
| 3  | content of question2                   | null    | 6         | 300  |
| 4  | content of second answer for question1 | 1       | 4         | null |
| 5  | content of first answer for question2  | 3       | 2         | null |
| 6  | content of question3                   | NULL    | 8         | null |
| 7  | content of first answer for question3  | 6       | 4         | null |
| 8  | content of second answer for question3 | 6       | 2         | null |
+----+----------------------------------------+---------+-----------+------+
```

And I have this query:

```
SELECT count(1)
 FROM qanda question
 JOIN qanda answer ON question.Id = answer.related
WHERE answer.related IS NOT NULL
  AND answer.user_id = 2
  AND question.free IS NULL;
```

As you know, query above returns the number of answers that belongs to free questions *(in this case, [it returns `2`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/281b18/7))*. Ok all fine. I also have this table:

```
// votes
+----+---------+-------+
| id | post_id | value |
+----+---------+-------+
| 1  | 2       |  1    |
| 2  | 3       | -1    |
| 3  | 2       |  1    |
| 4  | 8       | -1    |
| 5  | 1       |  1    |
| 6  | 4       |  1    |
| 7  | 2       | -1    |
| 8  | 8       |  1    |
| 9  | 8       | -1    |
| 10 | 8       | -1    |
+----+---------+-------+
```

And I need to eliminate the answers that have negative total score. So it should return `1` in this case. Because where `qanda.id = 8`, that answer has `-2` total vote score, So I don't want to count it. How can I do that?

Comment: can you please post your desired output.

Comment: @Suraz Expected output is just `1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to exclude posts whose total votes are less than zero is like this:

```
SELECT count(1)
FROM qanda question
JOIN qanda answer ON question.Id = answer.related
WHERE answer.related IS NOT NULL
AND answer.user_id = 2
AND question.free IS NULL
AND question.id not in (
  select post_id
  from votes
  group by post_id
  having sum(value) < 0)
```

The key part here is the `having sum(value) < 0` which select posts with net negative votes.

---

From comments...

To find users who have too many "bad" answers, you should probably return how many "good" answers they made and decide if overall they're a "bad" user. For example, a user that has 5 answers that are all bad is very different from a user with 1000 answers of which only 5 are bad, even though they both have 5 bad answers.

Try this:

```
select
    sum(score < 0) bad,
    count(*) total,
    sum(score < 0) / sum(.01) percent_bad
from (
    SELECT coalesce(sum(value), 0) score
    FROM qanda question
    JOIN qanda answer ON question.Id = answer.related
    LEFT JOIN votes ON votes.post_id = answer.id
    WHERE answer.related IS NOT NULL
    AND answer.user_id = 2
    AND question.free IS NULL
    AND answer.timestamp > subdate(now(), 365)
    GROUP BY answer.id
) scores
```

A couple of notes on some SQL Kung Fu in there:

- in MySQL, true is 1 and false is 0, so by summing a condition, you count how many times it's true. This is much simpler to code, and easier to read, than the clumsy `SUM(CASE ...)` expressions needed by other DBs
- diving a count by `SUM(.01)` (which I only just thought of BTW) is the briefest way to get a percentage, as it not only simplifies the expression, but concerts the answer to float so you automatically avoid integer arithmetic rounding

<sub>Disclaimer: Code may not compile or work as it was thumbed in on my phone (but there's a reasonable chance it will work)</sub>

Comment: Why `question.id not in (`? I mean why not `answer.id not in (` ?

Comment: @MartinAJ you could add that logic, but then you would be counting questions with non-negative votes that the user answered **with a non-negatively voted answer**, which I didn't detect from your question. If that is your intention, add a similar condition on answer.

Comment: Ah ok, upvote. Look, I don't want to count the number of questions at all. I don't even care about negative votes for questions. All I'm trying to do is banning an user who has written lots of bad **answers**. So I have to replace `question.id not in (` with `answer.id not in (` in your query, right?

Comment: Just for my information, if I want to restrict that query to just select the rows since last year *(not before that)*, Should I add this `. . WHERE date_time > unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR))` in the either inner or outer query? or both of them?

Comment: @stack put it in the outer query. you could add it to the inner query, but it would make no difference (it would increase the number of ids it couldn't be, but would only add ones that are already excluded by the outer query). I'm currently working on a new version of the query in response to OPs comments

Comment: Thank you for working on my needs, jut look, what stack said is a great  idea, can you please also add that time limitation for until last year?

Comment: *"it would increase the number of ids it couldn't be"* ... Now I'm wonder how a `WHERE` clause causes increasing the number of rows?

Comment: @stack sorry - other way around: adding a where clause to the inner query would reduce the rows but would only remove rows that don't matter

Comment: by the way +1 for your edited version .. seems delightful.

Comment: @stack and OP: I've added the time frame constraint

Comment: Great .. Just what's `GROUP BY answer.id` for? Seems useless to me, what you say?

Comment: @stack the group by is *essential*. Without it you will get exactly one row from the subquery. With the group by you get one row per answer. Note that you don't need to *select* an expression to *group* by it. Think of it like silently adding `answer.id` to the select clause.

Comment: Hi again. look, based on my website's policy, I don't need to get a percentage. So I will go with your first query. All fine, and thanks again for that. Just I'm worry *(a bit)* about that subquery in your first query. Currently it works quickly, But I worry about `Votes` table size. It might take too much time if it became too large.. Because it scans the whole of  `Votes` table and that scares me. anyway, are you sure that's the best query  for doing that?

Comment: @martin put an index on `votes(post_id)` and it will scale to millions of rows

Comment: Ok .. good. And my last consult: In reality, I have multiple post tables, and one of them is `qanda`. So there is a column named `table_code` in the `Votes` table which specifies each vote belongs to what post table. Anyway, I need to add `WHERE table_code = 15`  *( `15` is code of `qanda` table)* to the subquery. So can you please tell me what kind of index do I have need? `votes(post_id, table_code)` is fine? Or what?

Comment: Noted that OP and me are working on the same project.

Comment: @shaf yes, and yes

Comment: After lots of thinking I understand your **second query** is much more reasonable to introduce an user as *bad user*. I just need to add  this condition `votes.table_code = 15`. Ok, should I add that condition where exactly? on the either `WHERE` clause or `ON` clause of `LEFT JOIN`? *(I'm talking about your second query)*

Comment: @MartinAJ With left joins, you *must* put the condition within the join condition, otherwise you effectively force the join to be normal inner join. Your code should look like: `LEFT JOIN votes ON votes.post_id = answer.id and votes.table_code = 15`

Answer (score 0):

You can put another AND condition and within that have the select statement (summing value where post id = qanda.id ) for calculating the total vote score and evaluating it to greater than or equal to zero.

Comment: I guess I need one more `JOIN` clause to `votes` table.

Comment: Yes, you can put another join as well. Both achieve the same result

Answer (score 0):

Please try this once:

```
SELECT v.value val
FROM qanda q
INNER JOIN qanda q1 ON q1.related = q.id
INNER JOIN votes v ON v.id = q.user_id
WHERE q.free IS NULL 
AND q1.user_id = 2
AND v.value > 0
```