# How can I exclude posts whose total votes are less than 1?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my query:

```
SELECT count(1)
 FROM qanda question
 JOIN qanda answer ON question.Id = answer.related
WHERE answer.related IS NOT NULL
  AND answer.author_id = ?
  AND question.amount IS NULL
  AND answer.date_time >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(now() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR) AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(now() - INTERVAL 1 hour)
  AND answer.id NOT IN (
      SELECT post_id
      FROM votes
      WHERE table_code = 15
      GROUP BY post_id
      HAVING SUM(value) < 0 )
```

My query returns the number of user's answers that have either zero or a positive total votes *(total votes: 0, 1, 2, ...)*. Now I need to exclude the answers that have `0` total votes.

therefore I replace:

```
... HAVING SUM(value) < 0
```

with

```
... HAVING SUM(value) < 1
```

But it doesn't work as expected. I mean it still counts the answers that have zero total votes. What's wrong? and how can I fix it?

Comment: Why is it `AND answer.id NOT IN ()`? Remove the `NOT`

Comment: @juergend That `NOT` excludes the rows which matched by that subquery.

Comment: @MartinAJ -- but it also doesn't exclude the ones that have no records in that table.  Using `in` presumably would exclude those and changing the `having` criteria to >= 0 would imply the opposite to return the correct records as well...  With that said, I wasn't sure if you even needed the having criteria unless you have negative values...

Comment: @sgeddes *"The rows that have no records in `votes` table"* means total votes of those answers  are `0`. So it shouldn't be exclude  *(in my last version)*. But Now  I need to also exclude the answers that are equal to zero or less than zero total votes.

Comment: Table structure, sample data and expected results would be helpful then... As is, it's a little difficult to understand what's going on.  Even better would be a sqlfiddle.  Did you try my second suggestion using `in` with `having sum(value) > 0`?  Semantically that should be the same (again unless I misunderstand)...

Comment: @sgeddes If you need more details about my question, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39402489/how-can-i-count-the-number-of-posts-that-have-either-zero-or-positive-vote-score) is the old version of my current question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your inner query doesn't select posts that have **no** votes, so they *aren't* excluded. There are a couple of ways of solving this, but the easiest is to *reverse* the logic from *exclusion* to *inclusion*, ie "show posts that have total votes > 1":

```
SELECT count(1)
 FROM qanda question
 JOIN qanda answer ON question.Id = answer.related
WHERE answer.related IS NOT NULL
  AND answer.author_id = ?
  AND question.amount IS NULL
  AND answer.date_time BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(now() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR) AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(now() - INTERVAL 1 hour)
  AND answer.id IN ( -- remove "NOT"
      SELECT post_id
      FROM votes
      WHERE table_code = 15
      GROUP BY post_id
      HAVING SUM(value) > 0 ) -- change to > 0
```

---

As a join:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM (
  SELECT answer.id
  FROM qanda question
  JOIN qanda answer ON question.Id = answer.related
  JOIN votes ON votes.post_id = answer.id 
      AND votes.table_code = 15
   WHERE answer.related IS NOT NULL
   AND answer.author_id = ?
   AND question.free IS NULL
   AND answer.date_time BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(now() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
     AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(now() - INTERVAL 1 hour)
   AND answer.timestamp > subdate(now(), 365)
   GROUP BY answer.id
  HAVING SUM(votes.value) > 1) x
```

Comment: Great .. but look, why you didn't add `AND answer.date_time >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(now() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR) AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(now() - INTERVAL 1 hour)` in the subquery too?

Comment: @MartinAJ Because it will make no difference. Think about it.

Comment: Well that's pretty **strange** for me .. Even my friend has  asked a [separated question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39421039/should-i-try-to-reduce-selected-rows-in-the-subqueries) about it. Why do you think reducing the number of selected rows in the subquery doesn't make executing more fast? [Also this is a related comment.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39421039/should-i-try-to-reduce-selected-rows-in-the-subqueries#comment66167050_39421039)

Comment: Oh .. I guess you are missing this: `Votes` table also have a column named `date_time` *(I didn't mention that column in my previous question)*.

Comment: @MartinAJ I meant it won't make any difference to the rows returned. If you want to make it faster, you could try adding the where clause. The fastest would be a join instead of a subquery. I'll leave that to you to figure out.

Comment: I myself figured [it (using join instead of subquery)](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7ce009ee2003ee21b88b7645933dd4b4) out .. but sadly it doesn't return anything :-(

Comment: @MartinAJ do the count over a subquery: `select count(*) from (select answer.id ... group by answer.id having sum(votes) > 1) x` (don't leave out the `x`). Also, you can remove `LEFT`, since you *require* votes, there will always be a join to `votes` for the rows you want.

Comment: @MartinAJ also just noticed a typo in your query (both of them): it looks like `>=` should be `BETWEEN`. I've posted the join, and fixed that error.

Comment: Great, upvote .. thank you :-)  .. I guess I can also remove `HAVING` clasue if the condition is `HAVING SUM(votes.value) > 0`, right? *(since you have removed `LEFT`)*

Comment: @martin no, leave the `having`; you still need to restrict posts to those with positive vote total. BTW, this isn't the longest dialog I've had with a user to find a solution. But it's the second longest :/

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly, use `in` instead of `not in` and reverse your `having` criteria:

```
...
answer.id IN (
      SELECT post_id
      FROM votes
      WHERE table_code = 15 
      GROUP BY post_id
      HAVING SUM(value) > 0)
```

Comment: This solution seems incomplete to me. Because if I want to replace `NOT IN` with `IN`, then I have to add some other conditions into subquery too. Like that time limitation which is in the outer query `.. AND answer.date_time >=  ...` and some conditions else

Comment: @MartinAJ -- Guessing here a bit but edited -- you can add additional criteria as needed...

Comment: @Alex -- that's what I edited my question to do... Originally it was unclear that all data must exist in the `votes` table.  After comments, that became evident...